# Why would datetime picker controls be missing on a Windows forms dialog on some machines

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I am developing an Excel add in Visual Studio 2015. Target version is 2010. I tested it on a freshly provisioned machine with Excel 2016. Everything is fine and behaves as on my dev machine, except that two date time picker controls are missing from the dialog/form - the only form anyway. Machines are running Windows 7 and the .net runtime is 4.6.1. Was. I upgraded to 4.6.2 because on the Excel 2016 test machine someone saw that .Net version installed so I obliged, though I was pretty sure it won't solve anything.
At the same time a colleague with a Windows 7 machine too and Excel 2016 doesn't exhibit the problem. So it's not an Excel incompatibility between versions.
Any ideas what could cause this? Ideas of how to at least troubleshoot?

Comment: Brr, you give very few breadcrumbs to help you.  My crystal ball says that those DTP controls are near the right or bottom edge of the window.  Excel is a dpiAware program so your UI design will scale itself to match the DPI of the monitor.  So one thing you don't want to do is hardcode the form size in your code, the window will be too small and those controls won't be visible.

Comment: I have a feeling that's not the problem. This is a very small dialog with a drop down list two datetime picker controls and two buttons. Screen sizes and their resolutions are in the same ballpark. No mobile, no small screens. As I can't do to much troubleshooting on machines other than mine, to prove (a hunch of mine) that the controls are not even added to the controls collection of the form, they are just silently ignored I will dump a list of some info of each control that ends up in the list of controls for that form. It will just prove my point but won't tell me the cause.

Comment: @Mircealon, you can prove or disprove your hunch that the controls are/are not added to the form's control collection by iterating through them when the form is shown, and popping up a message box if found/not found. You can also make the form size very large to verify Hans Passant's hunch too.

Comment: @HardCode Yes, that's what I intend to do as soon as I can allocate the time. I asked the question more hoping that this happened to somebody else and they would know of the top of their heads. I'll post back my finding in a day or two.

Answer (score 0):

As promised I wrote a bit of code that lists all the controls added to the Controls collection of the form. I deployed that and to my surprise this time the datetime picker controls were displayed. The testing environment is not under my control and it is provided to me as virtual machines. Other than the troubleshooting code I did not add anything so I am stumped.

Anyway, one thing to remember out of all this is that if you write a handler for the ControlAdded event of the form it will be added to the designer form file after the statements that add the controls to the form. The alternative was to write a for loop and enumerate them in the Load event handler for the form. You can move the handler registration too before the Add() calls but it will be overwritten next time the designer generates new code.

If the above wouldn't offer enough information to solve the problem (very probable) then my next step would have been to use the Fuslogvw.exe to look for any assembly binding load failures, though I didn't have many hopes with that too.

If the issue occurs again, and especially if I find a solution, I will come back and update this.